# Erlang newbie question

Tags: erlang

From the past few hours I am trying to install and compile beepbeep framework sample application on Win XP Pro. Hope experts here can help me!

Here are the steps I am following http://www.planeterlang.org/en/planet/article/BeepBeep_A_Rails_like_framework_for_Mochiweb/

On step 3 when I enter the make in Erlang shell it's being accepted as atom instead of running the Makefile. So, I tried make:all() and the result is up_to_date which I guess is correct and that all the modules mentioned in makefile are compiled.

However on step 4 i get a syntax error-- "syntax error before: '/' " when I try to generate a new web application using the command ./script/new_beep.erl YouAppName “DestinationDirectory"

So in short, I am unable to use "make" as well as not able to create new web application using beepbeep source code.

Thanks in advance,
nand

Answer (score 3):

I think I found the solution to the problem that I am facing or should I say faced? :-) Here are the high level steps that I did to resolve make issues as well as shell script issues.Hope this is useful to someone!
1) installed Cygwin (all packages although not necessary).
2) Set up the cygwin environment variables to recognize the erlc.exe and erl.exe. This is done through cygwin.bat
3) Tried to "make" but failed. Apparently there seems to be a problem with the make utility that came along with cygwin download. Tried make:all() from Erlang shell and it worked fine and generated the necessary beam files.
4) Created a shell script pointing to the entry function (of the .beam file) and everything worked just fine :-) finally!

Following are the references that I used:
1) http://cs.nyu.edu/rgrimm/teaching/fa09-oop/windows-make.html
2) Chapter 6 of Joe Armstrong book. Thanks Joe!
3) http://blog.omega-prime.co.uk/?p=5

Answer (score 0):

You should enter `make` into your operating system's command line, and not the Erlang shell.
On windows you can install [gnumake](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm) to have a make environment.